# Invertibility in infinite dimensional HIlbert spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, inverse

Suppose the operator $A$ acts on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space and has the property that $A^\dagger A = 1$. **Can such an operator not be invertible?** For a finite dimensional Hilbert space, applying the determinate to $A^\dagger A = 1$ easily reveals invertibility, but I do not think I can apply the determinant logic in the infinite-dimensional case. **If there are such operators that are not invertible, what are some examples?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can happen. The canonical example is the unilateral shift. For instance take $H=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, and put
$$
Ax=(0,x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots). 
$$
It is straightforward to see that $A$ is an isometry, which immediately implies that $A^\dagger A=1$. But $A$ is not surjective. With just a tiny more work, one can see that
$$
AA^\dagger x=(0,x_2,x_3,\ldots). 
$$
Such an operator can be defined in any separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, by fixing an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ and defining $A$ as the linear operator that satisfies $Ae_n=e_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

As mentioned by David, the [Wold Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wold%27s_decomposition) guarantees that the only counterexamples are versions of this one.

Comment: In fact, this is in a sense the only example: one can show that any isometry on a Hilbert space is a direct sum of copies of unilateral shifts and possibly a unitary.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thank you very much

Comment: @Debbie: glad I could help!